Max size of the text in text box
I get a text in textbox. My problem is when I write longer text than the textbox size, the text box is scrolling, and a can write too long text. This text will be etching on a CNC machine, therefore I have only eg. 50mm for the text (The font type, size is fix)
The textbox1.text.lenght is not good for me, because it's control the number of the characters. The probelem is for example the "M" is weither then the "I", i can witer different character nubmer from "M" and from "I".
I need when the string is reach the end of my textbox, stop the writing or add an error messege.
Anybody has idea for this?
Best Regards,
Tibi

Take a look at TextRenderer.MeasureText Method, which may provide what you need.
